# how to add a page with AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) in drupal

Tags: drupal, amp-html

I'm already using amp with my content type but how can i use amp with a page that was build in a module or a page that was created using views?

Comment: See the AMP/WordPress initiative for clues.

Comment: here you go https://www.drupal.org/project/amp_optimizer